# VimL: check if Lua is supported

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-lua

How do I check if Lua is supported?

From my `.vimrc`, I only want to put an `if` around a Lua heredoc so that my config works in plain `vim` or versions of neovim which didn't support Lua (pre 0.5.0?).

What's the best way to check for Lua support in VimL?

Comment: if has('lua') ...

Comment: @Heptite `has('lua')` returns `0` in `NVIM v0.9.0`.  Surely this is a bug?

Answer (score 3):

All Neovim versions do support Lua. For Vim, you can check `has("lua")` return value. That is, `if has("nvim") || has("lua")` should work in most cases.

However, Vim may specifically depend on the presence of external Lua library in run-time. So executing Lua code may still fail even if `has("lua")` returns one.

So if you want to be 100% sure, you have to try it.

```
function! LuaWorks()
    try | return luaeval("1")
    catch | endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: Didn't `nvim` prior to v0.5.0 only have partial Lua support?

Comment: I just tested, and in the `catch` case, nothing is returned, which has `0` (the default) returned.

Comment: @TomHale 1) What you mean by "partial"? The Lua engine was always a builtin in Neovim. If it was missing some feature(s) you personally need then check for `has("nvim-0.5.0")` or such specifically. Otherwise, I don't have idea what are you talking about. 2) Yes, in VimScript zero is default return value. This is why I had it omitted. Putting it after "catch" doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Matt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42709/5324), I came up with this:

```
" Check for a working Lua:
function! HasLua()
  if has('nvim-0.5')
    return 1
  endif
  if ! has('lua')
    return 0
  endif
  " Check external lua works correctly
  try
    return luaeval("1")
  catch
    return 0
  endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to specify the exception(s) for `catch` (`:help :catch`). For example, I think as written if I Ctrl-C while that function happens to be executing it would give the wrong result instead of bubbling up the interrupt. Probably not what you want.